# How to mask passwords in 'watch' command?

Tags: scripting, password, watch

I am using `watch` to monitor the progress of a MySQL replication slave. The way I have it set up now, the password shows up in the header of the `watch` output. I am not exceedingly worried that someone will steal the password, but on principle I would prefer not to be showing a naked password to anyone who happens to wander up and look over my shoulder.

The command line I am currently using with `watch` is:

```
watch -n1 -d mysql -pmypass -e "'show slave status\G'"
```

Should I just bury the `mysql` command in a tiny little shell script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A better option than providing the password on the command line at all is to make a `~/.my.cnf` file with the credentials in it:

```
[client]
password=something
```

That way they are also protected against someone looking at the `ps` output, or your shell history.

That said, you can turn off the `watch` title entirely with the [`-t` or `--no-title` option](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch), which will:

> Turn off the header showing the interval, command,  and  current
>                 time  at  the top of the display, as well as the following blank
>                 line.

You do lose a little more information than you were wanting, but it's not hugely vital. Otherwise, a shell script also works, as you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

It will not only show up on your screen, but also in `ps` output, in your `~/.bash_history` (though that one should only be readable to you and the admins) and possibly in some audit or performance logs.

You should not pass passwords as arguments to commands. Arguments to commands should be considered public knowledge.

For mysql, use `~/.my.cnf` as [Michael has shown](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151472/22565) or in another file (readable only do yourself) passed as `--defaults-extra-file=the-file`

Comment: Good point about the ps output.

Answer (score 3):

Are you okay with typing the password when you run it?
You can read it in a bash script without making it visible in the terminal, saving to history, etc:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if ! IFS= read -rs -p "Enter password: " password < /dev/tty 2> /dev/tty
then
  echo "Password entry failed"
  exit 1
fi

somecommand -user me -password $password
```

Looking at the other answer, this *is* vulnerable to the `ps` problem, though, since there will be a process there for `somecommand`

Comment: This could work, as I trust all the admins on that system. I will keep the technique in mind in case I want to do a similar thing with any program that does not allow putting settings in a file like `.my.cnf`.